# Unable to add github action successfully to azure app service

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I'm new to azure services. I have created a sample Dot Net core 5.0 app and wanted to deploy it to Azure service. So I created a docker image first and using Visual studio I upload that docker image to the docker hub and then deploy it to the Azure service. Note that to this point azure app worked perfectly. Then I wanted to add Github to a created azure app, so I added repository to the deployment center. Please refer to below image.
[image]

My goal is to update the azure app service automatically, when I make any changes to the DotNet Core sample repo. However, when I make any changes repository actions get call but do not get deployed to the Azure app service. And it gives an error "**buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /tmp/buildkit-mount187611682/Dockerfile: no such file or directory**"  Please refer to the below image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance,
Yohan

Answer (score 1):

If the Dockerfile is already in the root folder and is named as `Dockerfile` then there is no need to specify the path you can just skip it.
[Here is how it will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXkQG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dockerfile has the same name as the one shown in your terminal, example:

> "buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to read
> dockerfile: open /tmp/buildkit-mount187611682/Dockerfile: no such file
> or directory"

In this case, your dockerfile´s name should be as "Dockerfile"

The dockerfile needs no extension, in Windows, you can create it with notepad++ and save it as "all types (.)"
`
You can try typing the full path of your dockerfile:

```
docker build -t X:X O:\Users\yyy\XX
```